# Calling a SOAP service from C# REST API

Tags: c#, rest, soap

I have a VBA code which calls a SOAP service and receives an XML response.
I want to write a C# REST API to call this SOAP service in a similar way.

Referring to the articles here I wrote a SOAP request but it does not works and returns the below error. I am able to call this SOAP service from the VBA code and also POST MAN. Can some one please explain what's wrong with my code?

```
 public class CallSOAPAPIController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Extract()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();

        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:inc=""http://www.test-xyz.com/""><soap:Body>Calendar @Year@Month@1</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
            }
        }

        return soapResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a soap webrequest to [Url]
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://test.production-xyz.com/listofemployees.do?getdetails=all&SOAP");

        webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        CallSOAPAPIController obj = new CallSOAPAPIController();

        string base64Credentials = obj.GetEncodedCredentials();
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

        return webRequest;
    }

    private string GetEncodedCredentials()
    {
        string m_Username = "XXXXXX";
        string m_Password = "XXXXXX";

        string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", m_Username, m_Password);
        byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
    }

}
```

The error I get : "The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorized"

[Unauthorized(401)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhpku.png)

Comment: *If I understand correctly.  you are building a REST-SOAP adapter service.  Rather than trying to parse SOAP directly, simply add a Web Reference (to the SOAP service) using Visual Studio.  This will generate code that does the request/response SOAP parsing automatically.*


[link 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tydxdyw9(v=vs.100).aspx)

[link 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx(v=vs.100).aspx)